# Тире или скобки при обособлении приложений?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Допустимо ли здесь тире при обособлении приложений? Или лучше поставить скобки?

Если же говорить о сумме технологий, применяемых при изготовлении разработанных нами и нами же изготавливаемых запорно-регулирующих устройств типа ДРПМ, то они базируются на принципах управления свойствами поверхности твердых тел – как металлов, так и неметаллов – путем создания наноразмерных покрытий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше оставить тире. Скобки являются более сильным знаком для уточняющих присоединительных конструкций, и в данном случае необходимости в них нет.